# In AngularFire2, how do I convert incoming json to objects

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using AngularFire2 to read data from Google's Cloud Firestore.  [The docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/#example-use) show how to receive an updated set of documents on each data change using `valueChanges()`:

```
this.items = db.collection<People>('people').valueChanges()
```

I also have a `People` class which defines some attributes (first and last name) and a function/method `fullName`,

```
export class People {
  public first: String = '';
  public last: String = '';
  constructor(...args) {
      [ this.first, this.last, this.active ] = args;
  }
  static MakePersonFrom(input: Any) {
      return Object.assign(new People(), input);
  }
  fullName() { 
      return `Honorable ${this.first} ${this.last}`; 
  }
}
```

The `People` class matches my documents in the `people` collection, which each have a first and last name.  I want to call `fullName` on elements of `this.items`, for example in an html template:

```
<ul><li *ngFor="person in people | async">{{person.fullName()}}</li></ul>
```

To make this work, I have subscribed to valueChanges and transformed each incoming document:

```
this.items = db.collection<People>('people').valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    map(listOfPeople => {
      return listOfPeople.map(person => {
        return People.makePersonFrom(person);
      });
    }),
    tap(item => {console.log('Converted', item); } ),
  );
```

I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this in AngularFire2. The `.pipe` code above is mostly boilerplate but for the class name.  Is there a variant of `valueChanges()` that can do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

I found that AngularFire2's behavior is consistent with [Angular itself](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response), as shown in this small excerpt from the HTTP chapter of the guide:

```
config: Config;

showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    // clone the data object, using its known Config shape
    .subscribe((data: Config) => this.config = { ...data });
```

They use the spread operator instead of `Object.assign` and are only dealing with one response, but it is otherwise the same.